# ssh-add -l does not show the location of the SSH key(s)

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

When I run `ssh-add -l`, it does not show the location of the SSH key(s). It outputs the following:

```
4096 SHA256:bBMtB9wL6RXRWhvx5M+LDox6A2gq61CDtZN9F4bi3Gw masoud@x.y (RSA)
2048 SHA256:QbCO5y5SX+CSHd6++yXPpJuWGrxGCx5liNktjz51ZWY masoud@x (RSA)
```

How can I make it shows the key location as well?

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: Are you storing your private keys anywhere other than the standard `~/.ssh` ?  As far as I know, `ssh-agent` does not cache the filename from which a key was loaded, so there is no option to display it.  You can compare fingerprints of your keys with the fingerprints listed by `ssh-add -l` to determine which key file corresponds to which fingerprint in the agent.

Comment: @user4556274 no I have seen some outputs show the filename such as https://blog.tinned-software.net/manage-ssh-keys-with-the-ssh-agent/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh-agent` does not cache the filename from which a key was loaded, so there is no option to display it.  The third field in the output of `ssh-keygen -l` is a free-form comment, so you have two options to display the filename in that field when listing the keys held by the agent:

1. When creating the key with [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen), manually specify the (expected) file path as the comment, instead of accepting the default comment:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"
   ```
2. When creating the key, manually specify *no* comment.  If a private key has no comment, then `ssh-agent` [will use the filename as a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375836/where-does-ssh-agent-get-the-names-it-uses-for-keys) instead:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C ""
   ```

For keys that already exist and have a comment *other than* the filename, there is not a way to list the filename via `ssh-add -l`.